# How can I set button background colours in Qt, even overriding the platform theme?

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt

I am building an [NES tile editor](http://inversethought.com/hg/tilerswift/file/tip) and I would like to set the background colour for the palette buttons. This works great,

```py
    def set_colour(self, colour_idx):
        self.colour_idx = colour_idx

        bgcolour = NES_PALETTE[colour_idx]
        qt_colour = QtGui.QColor(bgcolour)
        [r, g, b] = qt_colour.red(), qt_colour.green(), qt_colour.blue()
        luminance = (0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b)/256
        textcolour = 'white' if luminance < 0.5 else 'black'

        self.setText(f"{colour_idx:0{2}X}")
        self.setStyleSheet(f"color: {textcolour}; background-color: {bgcolour};")
```

and in most cases and gives me a very pretty result.

[image: tilerswift in full colour]

The problem is that Qt isn't obeying my system GTK2 dark theme. When I try to make it do so by setting the `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` environment variable, the result instead looks like this:

[image: tilerswift all dark]

The buttons all seem to have had their colours overridden by the system theme.

I thought maybe I could be more insistent and make sure the system theme doesn't override my button colours by calling `setPalette` instead of using CSS:

```py
    def set_colour(self, colour_idx):
        self.colour_idx = colour_idx

        bgcolour = NES_PALETTE[colour_idx]
        qt_colour = QtGui.QColor(bgcolour)
        [r, g, b] = qt_colour.red(), qt_colour.green(), qt_colour.blue()
        luminance = (0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b)/256
        textcolour = 'white' if luminance < 0.5 else 'black'

        self.setText(f"{colour_idx:0{2}X}")
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, qt_colour)
        self.setPalette(pal)
        self.setStyleSheet(f"color: {textcolour};")
```

But that didn't make any difference. Is this a Qt bug? Am I doing something wrong? I'm thinking that maybe I need to make my own custom widget so that its colour can't be overridden by the Qt theme, but I'd like to know if there's another solution.

**Edit**: I have attempted to define my own `paintEvent` method too,

```py
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        bgcolour = NES_PALETTE[self.colour_idx]
        qt_colour = QtGui.QColor(bgcolour)
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, qt_colour)
        self.setPalette(palette)
```

and that produced this result: [image: tilerswift with some colours]

Is the problem that GTK+ is the one drawing the buttons?

Comment: I dont have an answer, but that color picker is awesome, if the colors behind the buttons actually reflect what the buttons mean.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth Yeah, of course, the colour of the button shows what colour you want to pick for the tiles' 4-colour palette. The indices are the 6-bit colour indices that the NES is capable of displaying, with some repetitions (lots of NES colour indices map to black).

Answer (score 3):

Other than setting a style application-wide (or better, single widgets that actually require that, while keeping OS style consistency for other GUI elements), using stylesheets is still possible, as long as you use all required parameters.  For buttons (I suppose any QAbstractButton descendant), the border component is mandatory to ensure that the stylesheet is applied.

```
def setColor(self, qt_colour):
    r, g, b = qt_colour.red(), qt_colour.green(), qt_colour.blue()
    luminance = (0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b)/256
    textcolour = 'white' if luminance < 0.5 else 'black'
    self.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton {{
        color: {};
        background: {};
        border: 2px outset {};
        border-radius: 4px;
        }}
    QPushButton:pressed {{
        border-style: inset;
    }}'''.format(textcolour, qt_colour.name(), qt_colour.darker().name()))
```

Also, keep in mind that QPalette and stylesheets don't play well together. You have to choose to use either a palette or stylesheets, as using both of them can result in unexpected behavior, which depends on both the style and the widget type.

Besides that, the reason for which your `paintEvent` test didn't work is because the button is already fully painted when you used `super().paintEvent(event)`, and after that you're just setting the same palette as you did in your previous `set_colour` every time the button requires to be "painted", which happens *very often*: when it's shown the first time, when it's displayed after being hidden by any other window, when the mouse enters or exits it, etc...
For obvious reasons, this shouldn't be done: changing the palette already requires a repaint of the widget, which will make Qt call the paintEvent again. Luckily, Qt ensures that the new palette is actually different from the existing one before applying it (otherwise you'd have got a recursion), but, anyway, the paintEvent is not the best place for doing that.

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to work too. How did you know about "using stylesheets is still possible, as long as you use all required parameters"? What are the "required" parameters, is this documented?

Comment: You cannot combine QSS and QStyle at the same time since QSS internally creates a QStyle based on the QSS by eliminating the QStyle you tried to use.

Comment: @JordiGutiérrezHermoso I only found it out by trial and error; as far as I know, there's no official documentation about that, as it depends on the widget and how the style implements its drawing functions and metrics. Some widgets have "simpler" requirements (usually: border, color and background) and you can be almost sure that they will always be respected. The only actual problem is that you should also set some selectors; for example, `:disabled` is usually strongly suggested (to ensure that its visual representation reflects its enabled state) or `:pressed` for buttons.

Comment: @eyllanesc: According to my tests, you *can* combine QSS and QStyle, since a QSS behaves as some sort of "virtual style", and is actually applied "upon" the current style: whenever there's not enough "information" provided for widget styling, it automatically falls back to the current (default, explicit or command line) style set. You can even set a stylesheet and change the style afterwards: whenever the widget sheet parameters (required for that widget/style combination) are [not] set, they are applied according to the style.

Comment: @musicamante If you check the Qt code (I did it a few months ago to understand how QSS and QStyle interfere) you will find that QSS creates a style using "stylesheet" and depending on the style can be combined but that is not guaranteed in all styles. So depending on each style you can modify some small parts that "QSS style" does not override.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, I found out about that too, that's what I meant with my "fallback" comment (maybe I wasn't clear enough, sorry). That said, for the sake of *this* argument (buttons), setting border, background and foreground color should be enough for any style; obviously, if some *very* specific custom style comes in place (maybe through some QProxyStyle implementation?) some problems might be encountered, but, at that point, I think that this kind of stylesheet issue wouldn't be a real issue, as the programmer would probably be experienced enough to understand that by him/herself, right?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a limitation of native styles. They use pixmaps and therefore their colouring abilities are limited:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11089

The workaround is to force a non-native style on the widget that needs to be recoloured, like so:

```py
PLASTIQUE = QtWidgets.QStyleFactory().create("Plastique") 
# Native styles sometimes don't allow recolouring the
# background, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11089
self.setStyle(PLASTIQUE)
```

This produced the following result:

[image]

Comment: Right, the platform themes don't always adhere to the set global (QApplication) QPalette colors. The  most customizable built-in style (IMHO) is Fusion (is Plastique even included by default these days?).  Another option with platform themes is to use style sheets (which then actually uses QStylesheetStyle for the styled elements instead of platform style). Yet another (less practical) option is to set the QPalette on individual QWidgets which for some reason then makes them adhere to those colors even on platform themes.

Comment: @MaximPaperno Unless I'm doing it wrong, I attempted both stylesheets and QPalettes on individual widgets in the original problem description and neither of them changed the colours of the GTK2 widgets.

Comment: Remember that styles can be applied to single widgets too. This allows you to keep the application look consistent with the OS-wide system and apply the alternate style only to those widgets you need it for.

Comment: That... is exactly what I did in this answer, didn't I?